# Object detection model in a for loop - memory issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I've been trying to run object detection on a batch of images, but the graph keeps using more and more memory.
I think the variables are not being removed (when reassigned) and just keep getting added.
I tried resetting the default graph, clearing the session and manually deleting + garbage collection.

this is the for loop basically:

```
for i in range(num_images)
    box, m, s = detect(imgs[i])
    boxes.append(box)
```

this is detect

```
def detect(img):
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    detector_output = detector(tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0))
    classes = detector_output['detection_classes'][0]
    most_likely = tf.convert_to_tensor(classes[0])
    second_ = 20
    box = detector_output['detection_boxes'][0][0]
    box = tf.math.multiply(box, [height, width, height, width])
    box = tf.cast(box, tf.int16)
    del detector_output
    K.clear_session()
    return (box, most_likely)
```

I've been keeping track of memory and it increases linearly with the loop, so I'm thinking it's detector_output that just gets added each loop.

How could I solve this, what is a smarter way to do this?

PS the reason I have (thinking I have to) do it this way is because the models do not support batching:
https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/collections/object_detection/2

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `imgs` array could be taking a huge chunk of your memory as all the images are already loaded. You could try loading each image one by one and running the `detector()`

So your code has to change into something like this:

```
for name in image_names:
    # this function loads the image from disk and converts to a np array
    image = load(name)
    box, m, s = detect(image)
    boxes.append(box)
```

If you're still running out of memory, you can try saving `box` as a `.npy` file instead of appending to the `boxes` list, but the `boxes` list is unlikely to cause memory problems.

Comment: thank you very much.
I actually am already doing this. I ommited it from the code above for clarity, might have been a bad move. Apologies! I will try .npy , thanks a lot! I don't think so either, it's just about 9000 elements